# How to Initialize Variable when it is Populated by Network Request

Tags: swiftui

My Content view is:

```
struct ContentView {
   @State private var calendar = Bundle.main.decode(Calendar.self, from: "calendar.json")
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           .... Content that loops through calendar and displays events in a list
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.getData()
        }
    }
}

func getData() {
     let url = "<URL goes here>"
     let encoded = "<JSON FOR REQUEST>"
 
     var request = URLRequest(url: url)
     request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
     request.httpMethod = "POST"
     let encoder = JSONEncoder()
     if let data = try? encoder.encode(encoded) {
         request.httpBody = data
     }
     URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data1, response, error in
     // DECODE the response and process the data
         if let data1 = data1 {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let calendar = try? decoder.decode(IDCCalendar.self, from: data1)
            {
                self.calendar = calendar
            }
            else {
                print("Does not decode correctly")
            }
        }
        else {
            print("error with data1")
        }

 }.resume()
}
```

Here is my problem: The calendar variable needs to be initialised, so I am initialising it with dummy data from a file called calendar.json. Ideally, I'd just like to declare
@State private var calendar : Calendar
and have the network request populate the variable. Using the dummy data approach, when the app loads up, the dummy data appears first, and then gets replaced with actual data when the network call finishes up.

Any suggestions to solve this problem will be most appreciated.

Comment: There's no getting around the fact that the network request will take time. What about displaying a loading indicator until the data is ready?

Comment: I am okay with displaying a blank screen with a loading indicator till the network request returns the result. Here, I am forced to initialize the calendar variable with dummy data, which is non-blank and gets displayed, which is my problem.

The real problem is, how to get around the problem that variables need to be initialled, in my case, the calendar variable, which makes sense only when the network request returns the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an optional value, you don't need to set it with an initial value. Your `View` can render conditionally depending on if the variable is `nil` or has a value.

In general, async requests should not be done inside a `View`, so I've moved the logic to an `ObservableObject`:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var calendar : CalendarModel?
    
    func getData() {
        //get data from API and set self.calendar with result
    }
}

struct ContentView {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if let calendar = viewModel.calendar {
                    //use `calendar` variable here
                } else {
                    Text("Loading...")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.getData()
        }
    }
}
```

You could also refactor the calendar view into its own component (with a non-optional property) by doing something like this:

```
struct ContentView {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if let calendar = viewModel.calendar {
                    CalendarView(calendar: calendar)
                } else {
                    Text("Loading...")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.getData()
        }
    }
}

struct CalendarView : View {
    var calendar : CalendarModel
    
    var body: some View {
        //render calendar
    }
}
```

*(Note: I used CalendarModel since you didn't include the code for your types and you used both `Calendar` and `IDCCalendar` and I wasn't sure what the difference was. Also, beware of namespace collisions with `Calendar` since there's there's already a type named that in Foundation)*

Comment: This is beyond amazing jnpdx, thank you for such a rich answer, I greatly appreciate your time and kindness. And apologies for being sloppy with Calendar/IDCCalendar, they are the same variable.